# How to fix 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' while adding to list

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to add items to a list but I am facing the following

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

error while adding an item. I'm using BOT Framework.

I have tried changing `List`to `ConcurrentBag` also but it doesn't solve the issue.

```cs
public static async Task refreshCategoryLuis(ITurnContext turnContext)
{
    var luisCategoryIntents = await getCatagoryLuisIntentsList("*****-********-******-****");
    ConcurrentBag<string> categoryList = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= luisCategoryIntents.Length; i++)
    {
        categoryList.Add(luisCategoryIntents[i].Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i` can not equal `Length` because when it is, it crosses the bound so `<=` needs to be `<`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= luisCategoryIntents.Length; i++)
```

This line needs to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < luisCategoryIntents.Length; i++)
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking, totally missed this!